# How to add readable text paragraph on background with mixed colors in Illustrator 2020

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, readability

Can you please explain how to add readable text paragraph to background with various colors ? When background and foreground colors match then words or phrases are not distinct. I need readable text on such backgrounds. 
Thank you.

Comment: The "meme" format. White sans-serif bold text with black outline.

Comment: there are a bunch of other similar questions, for example https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29256/text-not-very-readable-on-different-image-backgrounds

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/stroke-object.html

Comment: Thank you. It possible to add outline to text and NOT to bunch of converted vector letters ? So working (to add an edge around type) directly with type is not possible ? Only converting first ?

Comment: Yes, you can add a stroke around editable text if that's what you are asking. In the Appearance panel, add a stroke, and drag the fill above the stroke, then select a fill colour. [See example](https://imgur.com/IUlKzhC).